# Start ID value from a user defined number in Ebean, Play-framework 2.5.4 java

Tags: java, mysql, database, playframework, ebean

I am using Play-framework 2.5.4 (Java). I am using Ebean as ORM.

This is My Model class :

```
    @Entity
    public class MyModel extends Model
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue()
        public Long ID;
   }
```

What I am  trying to achieve is,

- value of ID should be **8 digit number**
- it should **unique**
- **it should start from 10000000**
- i.e first ID should be 10000000 and second 100000001 and so on.

The **default value** of  ID generating now is 1,2,3,4 and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom UID generator like http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/id.

```
public class ModUuidGenerator implements IdGenerator {

  @Override
  public Object nextValue() {
    return 9999999l + ModUUID.newShortId();
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "shortUid";
  }
}
```

Always incrementing by 1 can cause concurrency issues, but this does force that each id > 9999999l.

Comment: Thanks for  answering. I will try it out.